# Prove that random variables are independent?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

If I have two random variables, say A and B, which are both discrete, can I prove that they are independent by proving that $E[A*B] = E[A]*E[B]$ ?

Comment: No, see e.g. [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/305687/70569) for an example of uncorrelated yet dependent discrete r.v.'s.

Comment: And indeed $E[AB]=E[A]\, E[B]$ is either the definition of *uncorrelated* or a direct consequence of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**They are uncorrelated**

$$
\begin{aligned}
Cov(A,B) &= \mathbb{E}(AB) - \mathbb{E}(A)\mathbb{E}(B) \\
&= 0 \ \ (\because \ \ \mathbb{E}(AB) = \mathbb{E}(A)\mathbb{E}(B) \ \ )
\end{aligned}
$$

since covariance is $0$, their Pearson correlation is $0$.

---

**They can be dependent**

Say

$$
P(A = -1) = P(A = 0) = P(A=1) = 1/3 \\
B= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{(if } A=0) \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

then $\mathbb{E}(A) = 0, \mathbb{E} (AB) = 0$, but $B$ obviously depends on $A$.